# Arrays and array indexing

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, indexing

I have two arrays, array1 and array2. I understand that the first element in an array is 0.

```
array1 = [a, b, c, d,....z]
array2 = [1, 2, 3, 4,.....26]
```

So, if I say:

```
array1[0] = a
```

but, I am wanting:

```
array1[1] = a
array[2] = b
array[26] = z
```

I am new to Python 2.7 (third day learning) and learning about arrays and indexes, so this crossed my mind. Is this possible? I tried using loops such as:

```
 for i in range(26)
     i = array2  # barely started learning loops so parden me if this makes me look like I do not know what I am doing
```

I also know that I can just assign variables such shown below. This takes up a lot of space!

```
 array2[0] = a
```

I am sure once I progress more using Python, I will figure this out, but in the meantime, I figured it would not hurt to ask.

Comment: Why do you need `a` at index `1` and not `0`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to fetch `a` when `1` is asked for use a closure that translates locations:

```
def fetch_with_shift(seq, shift):
    def fetch(x):
        return seq[x - shift]
    return fetch
```

Use like this:

```
my_fetch = fetch_with_offset(s, 1)
my_fetch(1) # 'a'
```

**Note:** There is also already a string for that in the `string` module:

```
from string import lowercase
s = lowercase # "abc...z"
```

Comment: I am going to look more into detail on fetch. What if the pair of arrays are not so simple such as keeping array1 the same but change array2 = [123, 3453, 5576....]. Can this work for array1[123] = a?

Comment: You'll have to explain what problem you're solving. It's highly unlikely to be that complicated as to require embedded offsets in lists.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for your help. I am just thinking of different scenarios where I am using another array as an indexing value (if this makes sense) instead of the traditional 1 = 0, 2 = 1, 3 = 2, etc. Not working on any problem in particular but just critically thinking about the concepts I am currently reading about.

Comment: @Caroline.py this is uncommon enough for it to not bother you. Stick to the known standards (starting from 0 is one of them) and it's unlikely you'll run into a problem such as this sooner than you'll be able to solve it quickly.

Comment: @ReutSharabani for a set shift value, this is overkill, especially for beginners.

Answer (score 0):

You can shift the array over by concatenating a `None` value to the front.

```
array1 = ["a", "b", ... "z"]
new_array = [None] + array1
```

Then, `array1[1]` will be `a`, and `array1[2]` will be `b`.